# cakePHP 2.3 delete cached view for action

Tags: cakephp

When using the CacheHelper and specifing an $cacheAction,  I can't find a way to delete a specific cached view when the content has changed! Is that right?

I don't want to delete all cached views with Cache::clear() because this would delete all my cached views.

I hope someone can verify.Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can provide some conditional criteria in callbacks to delete the specific cached views.

1. Reinitialize a new $cacheAction in callback with the specific view set the time to 0.

Ref: [Official Link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html#clearing-the-cache)